# Laravel Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel response in index.php takes over a second to execute

Tags: laravel, optimization, amazon-ec2, laravel-5, amazon-rds

I've been running some benchmark tests to find out why my application was running tremendously slow. Our application runs on an ec2 m3 instance with a mysql database on RDS. At first I thought it had something to do with RDS or a bad configuration. But as I started putting time checks in the code I came to the conclusion that as optimized as my code was - apparently the laravel kernal itself was taking a long time to execute.

In one of my main controllers the average execution time for all the code within the controller was around 200 - 175ms.

However the page would load taking an excruciating 1.3 seconds! There was definitely nothing wrong in the code for the controller so I figured something else must be causing the issue so I benchmarked the base code in the index.php file in the public directory of Laravel application and found that creating a Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel object and getting/sending the response alone took 1120ms!

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
// FROM HERE ->
$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');


$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();
//<--to here takes 1120 ms of which 200 ms is my code in the controller

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I'm assuming this is a framework issue but how can I overcome this - a one second average response time is unacceptable here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there might be thousands reasons for this. What you should do is profile your code to verify what takes so long.

But the first thing I would consider is database connection and queries that are executed. If you execute for example 10 queries and each takes 100ms, queries execution will take 1s, so you might get total 1.3 seconds and it's nothing strange.

So you should verify your code what exactly is happening, verify execution time for simple controller action (that only returns some string for example), verify what providers are loaded etc because each such thing can affect general performance.